# paramiko equivalent of "cat File.gz | ssh addres script.sh" in python 3.7

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Command i'm trying to run using paramiko in python 3.7:
Windows:

```
type file.ext4.gz | ssh user@address sudo update.sh
```

Mac:

```
cat file.ext4.gz | ssh user@address sudo update.sh
```

From the cmd / terminals and from .bat / .sh this works, after entering the password. I've been working on a simple python gui (PysimpleGui) to allow the user to fo this, but without the need to enter the password (this is saved from initial connection).

I've tried:

```
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(config["IP_ADDRESS"], username=config["USERNAME"], password=config["PASSWORD"], timeout=5)    
    a = client.open_sftp()
    a.put(file_location, "sh update.sh", callback=sent)
```

While this works to send the file, it doesn't run it and gives the error:

```
OSError: Failure
```

I don't want to do this in subprocess, as this tool is to prevent the use of terminal for the "end user"

I've been beating my head against this for 2 days now. Thank you.

EDIT:

Here is the STDIO Code:

```
def send_ssh(value, input=None):
    if input:
        transport = client.get_transport()
        channel = transport.open_session()
        channel.exec_command(value)
        with open(input, "rb") as file:
            for chunk in iter(functools.partial(file.read, read_size), b''):
                if channel.send_ready():
                    channel.sendall(chunk)
                if channel.recv_ready():
                    print(channel.recv(1024).decode().strip())
                if channel.recv_stderr_ready():
                    print(channel.recv_stderr(1024).decode().strip())
        while not channel.exit_status_ready():
            if channel.recv_ready():
                print(channel.recv(1024).decode().strip())
            if channel.recv_stderr_ready():
                print(channel.recv_stderr(1024).decode().strip())
    else:
        w, r, e = client.exec_command(value, get_pty=True)
        error = e.read().strip().decode()
        if error != "":
            return error
        else:
            return r.read().strip().decode()
```

Once the file is cat to the script it's the verified by the script. I worked around this by just using SFTP to send the file and running my

```
cat file | sudo script.sh
```

this works, but does require that i transfer a 600mb file (thankfully always over a local connection (LAN)) each time. The above code does transfer the file, but it doesn't complete. If i just try sending it via `for line in file:` i'll corrupt.

Comment: Your original shell command doesn't use the sftp subsystem at all; there's no reason for your paramiko implementation to do so either. Just connect the file to the remote process's stdin.

Comment: If your goal is _security_, that's something you should fix from the server side, not the client side. You can configure sshd to be able to run only a single, specific command when a session is started as a specific user or with a specific key. Do that, instead of trusting the client to provide only the command you intend or expect.

Comment: Not secuitiy, just for ease of use, as the original .bat / .sh had you enter the password 6 times. I tired using stdin, but i hand, maybe i was just impatient. i'll have to look if there is a way to print the output as well. The scrip will output as it's reading the data from the cat.

Comment: There are other ways to use openssh on the command line and not have to enter a password more than once. Look at the `ControlMaster` setting, aka SSH multiplexing. Even better, stop using passwords and switch to RSA authentication with a key loaded into an agent or stored on a smartcard.

Comment: ...anyhow, if you showed _how_ you tried to feed the file contents to the remote command's stdin, we might be able to make concrete observations about why it didn't work; as opposed to trying to upload to a command over sftp, which isn't ever _expected_ to work in the first place.

Comment: updated the initial post to add the stdio code. i got it working with a work around, but it involves sending the .gz file to the device, then using cat on it. it's faster this way but not ideal, as space is a premium.

Comment: There's really _never_ a good reason to use `cat` to read just one file. `cat somefile | somecommand` is worse in every way than `somecommand <somefile`, or its equivalent `<somefile somecommand`. In particular, doing that forces the command to read from a FIFO that's written to by a separate program (`/usr/bin/cat`) that's _itself_ reading from the file, instead of just letting your original command read direct from the file in the first place.

Comment: ...that's an even bigger deal when your program is something like `wc -c` or `tail` that could operate in constant time if given a real file handle, but when given a FIFO has to read front-to-back, because while you can tell the operating system to jump around in a file handle, tell you its size, tell you your current position, etc... can't do any of that with a FIFO.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping things simpler, below we're using threading to allow synchronous APIs to be used rather than needing to write explicit asynchronous code:

```
import shutil

client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect('user@address')

# here's the important part: we're using the file handles returned by exec_command()
update_stdin, update_stdout, update_stderr = client.exec_command('sudo update.sh')

# copy stdout and stderr from the remote thread to our own process's stdout and stderr
t_out = Thread(target=shutil.copyfileobj, args=[update_stdout, sys.stdout]); t_out.start()
t_err = Thread(target=shutil.copyfileobj, args=[update_stderr, sys.stderr]); t_err.start()

# write your local file to the remote stdin, in the foreground: we don't exit until done.
shutil.copyfileobj(open('file.ext4.gz', 'r'), update_stdin)
update_stdin.close()

# optional, but let's be graceful: wait for the threads to exit, and collect exit status
t_out.join(); t_err.join() 
result = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
print(f"Remote process exited with status {result}")
```